# phpexcel setprintara not working

Tags: php, phpexcel

I need to print selected area to pdf. I used

`$phpExcelObj->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setPrintArea('F1:O56');`

for setting up the print area. But its not working for me. I get the entire worksheet as pdf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because setPrintArea() doesn't do what you think.

When an Excel workbook is opened in MS Excel, it's possible to print a specified area of a worksheet rather than the whole worksheet by specifying the print area. That's the purpose of the setPrintArea() method, to define that. It applies when the file is saved as an Excel file (Excel5 or Excel2007 Writers), and then opened again in MS Excel.

It does not apply to any other writers. It does not tell PHPExcel only to save only part of a worksheet when using a writer. The Writers will always save the whole worksheet as defined in the PHPExcel object, whether to Excel formats, or to CSV or HTML or PDF. If you want to save only part of the worksheet, then you'll need to `remove` the parts of the sheet that you don't want by deleting rows and columns.